# Задержка в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пыталась сделать чтобы объект пропадал на 0.1 секунду, а потом появлялся, но он только пропадает, обратно не появляется, unity 5.6.7f1.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class StarScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private int chanse;
    public SpriteRenderer star;

    void Update () {
        chanse = Random.Range (0, 100);
        if (chanse == 1) {
            star.color = new Color (star.color.r, star.color.g, star.color.b, 0);
            Invoke ("wait", 0.1f);
            star.color = new Color (star.color.r, star.color.g, star.color.b, 255);
        }

    void wait () {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы меняете цвет, запускается что-то там куда-то там, что выполнится **через** секунду, а не остановит текущий код на 1 секунду. Для таких вещей нужно свою корутину писать:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StarScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public SpriteRenderer star;

    private IEnumerator blinkCoroutine;

    void Update () {
        if (Random.Range (0, 100) == 1 && blinkCoroutine == null) {
            blinkCoroutine = Blink(0.1f);
            StartCoroutine(blinkCoroutine);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Blink(float waitTime) {
        star.color = new Color (star.color.r, star.color.g, star.color.b, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        star.color = new Color (star.color.r, star.color.g, star.color.b, 255);
        blinkCoroutine = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проще.

1. Вариант:

```
   //Твой объект который будет  выключаться и включаться
    public GameObject game;

    private void Start()
    {

        //1. Укажи метод который будет вызываться.
        //2. Укажи изначальную вызова метода, сейчас поставлен 0.5f это стартовая время.
        //3. Укажи время сколько будет повторяться метод, сейчас поставлен 5.
        InvokeRepeating("ActiveObject", 0.5f,5);
    }

    void ActiveObject()
    {
        //Объект выключается и включается.
        game.SetActive(!game.activeSelf);
    }
```

2 вариант:

```
    public SpriteRenderer star;
    //Делаем галку для плавного появление звезды.
    public bool act;
    //добавляем управление над альфом, по умолчанию стоит 1. 
    public float Alpha = 1;
    //добавляем скорость появление.
    public float speed =1;

    private void Start()
    {

        //1. Укажи метод который будет вызываться.
        //2. Укажи изначальную вызова метода, сейчас поставлен 0.5f это стартовая время.
        //3. Укажи время сколько будет повторяться метод, сейчас поставлен 5.
        InvokeRepeating("ActiveObject", 0.5f,5);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Вводим ограничение для альфы что бы он не ушёл за пределами 1.
        Alpha = Mathf.Clamp(Alpha,0,1);
        //Привяжем альфу к звезде.
        star.color = new Color(star.color.r,star.color.g,star.color.b,Alpha);

        if (act)
        {
            //Скорость добавление.
            Alpha += Time.deltaTime * speed;

        }
        else
        {
            //Скорость убавление.
            Alpha -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
        }
    }

    void ActiveObject()
    {
        //Включаем галку и выключаем.
        act = !act;
    }
```